# Landing Hazards on Pluto

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft, planetary-science

This is for a fiction project I'm working on. Assuming it becomes possible to someday land on Pluto, what hazards might be encountered given what we've learned about its surface makeup?

Comment: Do you just want to land, or do you also want people walking around in spacesuits? The latter seems a lot harder. Probably better to land on one of the water ice regions than the predominant nitogen ice, since the latter will boil off violently from your waste heat.

Comment: Yes, there's an EVA and this is exactly the kind of natural hazard I was thinking of. More please!

Answer (score 4):

The primary difficulties I can think of are the sparse atmosphere and the temperature. [Pluto's atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Pluto) is incredibly thin, to the point that it is functionally useless for aerobraking or parachutes on descent. This means that any lander would have to burn a lot of fuel on descent.

Since Pluto is [so cold](https://www.space.com/18563-pluto-temperature.html), power supply is also an issue. Battery life would be short due to the temperature, so another form of power (like an RTG) would be required for a mission of any serious length.

Comment: Escape velocity is only 1200 m/s, versus 2400 m/s for the moon.

Comment: So an accomplished feat, but still worthy of note.